# AWS : Using S3 and Cloudfront with wordpress installed in EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am a completely new user of AWS and want to host a wordpress site there.

I successfully launched an EC2 instance,SSHed and installed LAMP stack and then wordpress. Everything is working fine but I want to use S3 for storage of static files than EBS.

I read many tutorials and implemented them.
1.Made a bucket in S3.

2.Launched my distribution in cloudfront with S3 bucket as origin.

3.Installed W3Cache plugin in wp and configured it.

But nothing worked. When I load my index page, I do see request coming from cloudfront.net but all the site assets are showing and 403 forbidden error.

I also tried making my bucket PUBLIC , but the problem persist. Rather I was billed for 0.10$ showing I have exceeded 20,000 GET and PUT requests.

I don't know when that happened, I barely have any traffic in my site(max 1-2 users) at this time.

Can anyone please explain whats going on and enlighten me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the Amazon Web Services Plugin and then the WP Offload S3 plugin. You will need to enter your Amazon secret and access keys in the php-config file. Before doing so I'd recommend you to create a user who has only access to S3 and CloudFront.

Also, if you are new to AWS, it's important you take your time to "harden" the WP installation. There are a number of ways you can achieve this.

[This article explains a lot about it.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) You don't want anyone to hack the file containing your AWS keys or next time you might be looking at thousands of dollars instead of cents.

Finally, if all of that fails, I'd recommend [WP Engine](https://wpengine.com) as hosting platform, but it's not cheap.